# What is the type of a lambda?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I've seen code like this:

```
std::sort(x, x + N, 
    // Lambda expression begins
    [](float a, float b) { 
        return std::abs(a) < std::abs(b); 
    });
```

Obviously the 3rd parameter of `std::sort` is a type that can hold the lambda. But what is that type? `std::sort` is so heavily overloaded I can't decipher it.

(I'm thinking of building up a list of functions: am thinking of using lambdas rather than function pointers as the latter have to have broadly the same parameter list).

I guess I could write

```
auto letTheComplerSortOutTheType =
        [](float a, float b) { 
            return std::abs(a) < std::abs(b); 
        });
```

but that won't help me when it comes to using a container.

Comment: You can always try printing it; `std::cout << typeid(foo).name();`

Comment: If you run this in a debugger and look, you'll see some garbled up name the compiler chose for the type. Each lambda is a new unique type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The type of lambda is *unique*, known to the compiler. In your code, `std::sort` is a function template, whose third parameter is a *template parameter* which is deduced by the compiler, for the lambda you pass to the function.

Usually you don't *need* to know the type of the lambda as it is defined by the compiler for you, something like below:

```
//generated by the compiler
struct __unique_lambda_defined_by_compiler  //arbitrary ugly name!
{
       bool operator()(float a, float b) const { 
                return std::abs(a) < std::abs(b); 
       }
};
```

So your code translates to this:

```
//translated by the compiler
std::sort(x, x + N, __unique_lambda_defined_by_compiler());
```

---

Note that if you want to have a container of lambda (and function pointers!), then you could use `std::function` to erase the type of the lambda (and function pointers), something like this:

```
 std::vector<std::function<bool(int,int)>> callbacks;

 callbacks.push_back([](int, int) { ... });  //the lambda must return bool
 callbacks.push_back([](int, int) { ... });
 callbacks.push_back([](int, int) { ... });

 bool compare(int,int) { ... } 

 callbacks.push_back(compare); //store normal function as well!
```

Comment: Ah. Makes perfect sense. That explains all those *funny numbers* when I hover over the lambda type!

Comment: plus: if you want to put it an a container it is useful to know what types a lambda can be bound to. so in your case you could (probably) use a vector< function<bool(float,float)> > . so in the end you really don't need to know the exact type.